# In PHP, how to find out composer's installation mode (prod/dev)?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'd like to know, how to determine if composer's [install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) command was performed with or without `--no-dev` during run-time in PHP. composer.json or composer.lock does not have this information. How can I find that out?

Comment: Why do you care for this? What kind of problem do you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This can be found out by using the class [InstalledVersions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#installed-versions), which is part of composer 2 and which is available to any composer driven project (can be found in directory `vendor/composer`).

```
use Composer\InstalledVersions;

$rootPackage = InstalledVersions::getRootPackage();

if ($rootPackage['dev'] === true) {
    // was installed with --dev (which is default) 
    // and not with --no-dev option
}
```

InstalledVersions uses the file `installed.php` (which can also be found in the directory `vendor/composer`), in order to get information about the installation.

You can try installing the project with and without --no-dev and see how root package's 'dev' entry changes then.